# Rails and MiniTest: How to write tests for something in app/lib/mymodule (Class not found)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

Rails 5.2 here.
I want to test a class defined in `app/lib/legacy/export.rb`:

```
# app/lib/legacy/export.rb
module Legacy
  class Export
    def initialize ; end
  end
end
```

However, a test in `test/services/legacy_export_test.rb`

```
# test/services/legacy_export_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class LegacyExportTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'can be initialized' do
    Legacy::Export.new
  end
end
```

will spit out `NameError: uninitialized constant Legacy::Export`.

It works well if I put the class definition in `app/lib/export.rb` (and remove the `module` definition).
I can also reference this class in Controllers and in the rails console (`rails c`).

Trying to reference the class starting with the top-level-"namespace" (`::Legacy::Export`) does not help either. I find answers to questions how to reference `lib` folders (and subdirectories) in the `test/` folder, but this is not what I need.

`require 'lib/legacy/export` will tell me `cannot load such file`, as will `require 'legacy/export'`.

I assumed that the (Auto-)Load-stuff of Rails and MiniTest are the same, but obviously there is some additional configuration to be done.

What has to be done? Where would I find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your class namespace / class path doesn't match how [Rails autoloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) works out of the box.

When you use a class that wasn't previously declared, Rails by default will look on specific paths (defined on `config.autoload_paths`)

- app/controllers
- app/controllers/concerns
- app/models
- app/models/concerns
- ...

When you use `User` for the first time, as it's not defined (yet) it will loop over those paths and try to require app/controllers/user.rb, app/controllers/concerns/user.rb, app/models/user.rb, until it founds the `User` class

if your class is namespaced as Legacy::Export, then it will look for app/models/legacy/export.rb, app/models/concerns/legacy/export.rb, app/controllers/legacy/export.rb, etc.

That's why it can't find your class: Your file is located on `app/lib`, that's not within the paths Rails use to look for.

There are different solutions:

#### Option #1

Require the file explicitly. (The Ruby way)

`require_relative '../../app/lib/legacy/export'`

#### Option #2

Add `app/lib` to `autoload_path` (in `config/application.rb`)
(The Rails Way)

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join("app/lib")
  end
end
```

#### Option #3

Adapt namespace to match what autoloading expects (instead of changing the configuration)

Example: move you file to something like `app/models/legacy/export.rb`

Comment: If you want to learn more details about how Rails handle autoloading, you can take a look on the documentation about [autoloading and reloading constants](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Comment: I will try that end of this weekend, but something seems still odd: `rails c` and Controllers can access this class. Or is it that these are not autoloaded, but in the "normal" LOAD_PATH?